# Variável não definida, mesmo estando definida

Tags: javascript, node.js

Fiz uma classe, na qual salva dentro de um array login e password do usuário:

```js
function AccountManager() {
    this.accounts = {};
}

AccountManager.prototype.createAccount = (login, password) => {
    this.accounts[login] = password;
};

module.exports = AccountManager;
```

E no index.js, criei uma conta test:

```js
var accountManager = new lib.AccountManager();
accountManager.createAccount("test", "test");
```

Porém diz que que o `accounts` é indefinido.

> ```
> this.accounts[login] = password;
>                          ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot set property 'test' of undefined
>
> at AccountManager.createAccount (c:\users\natha\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\WarfaceXmpp\WarfaceXmpp\lib\Utils\AccountManager.js:6:23)
> at Object.<anonymous> (c:\users\natha\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\WarfaceXmpp\WarfaceXmpp\app.js:6:16)
> at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
> at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
> at Timeout.Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:605:10)
> at ontimeout (timers.js:386:14)
> at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creio que o uso de `(login, password) => {` faz o comportamento mudar, ao invés de acessar `this` o `this` do "objeto" o `this` assume o mesmo valor de [`global` (node.js)](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) ou [`window` (se for um navegador)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window), então para ajustar faça isto:

```js
function AccountManager() {
    this.accounts = {};
}
AccountManager.prototype.createAccount = function(login, password) {
    this.accounts[login] = password;
};

AccountManager.prototype.test = function() {
    console.log(this.accounts);
};

var x = new AccountManager();
x.createAccount("test", "test");
x.createAccount("foo", "bar");
x.test("test", "test");
```

Comment: Sua resposta e a do @Walter Gms funcionaram perfeitamente, infelismente não consigo votar em duas repostas, mas como não conheço muito sobre estrutura de classes em javascript vou marcar esta.

Comment: @sysWOW32 considero a dele correta, mas a minha foi a que explicou a questão do comportamento do *arrow function*, não basta dar um código que funcione, explicar aonde falhou também é importante para ajudar quem pergunta e foi isto que eu fiz =) ... depois vou editar a resposta para adicionar detalhes sobre o ES6

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Esse código está dentro de uma classe?
O `this` quando dentro de uma classe é o escopo das propriedades da classe, comumente definidos no `constructor()` da classe...

```
class Teste {
    constructor() {
        this.title = 'Mensageria';
    }
    teste(){
        this.title = 'teste' // isso funciona
    }
}
```

Se não existe a classe, o `this` passa a ser a `function`, por isso o erro.

Comment: interessante, pensei que já colocando this.propriedade já estaria acessível. Eu realmente ainda não sei como trabalhar com classes em javascript.

Comment: Só tem um problema nesse código, `teste()` ou `function teste()` ?

Comment: teste() sem function :)