# Lambdas do Java são equivalentes a Closures do JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, expressões-lambda, programação-funcional, closures

Eu comecei a estudar programação funcional e estou um pouco confuso sobre estes dois itens.

**Minha questão é:** Lambdas Java são equivalentes a Closures do JavaScript? Caso não o sejam, qual a diferença entre elas?

Obrigado.

Comment: Acho que essa resposta no SO internacional ajuda : https://stackoverflow.com/a/220728

Comment: Note que no JavaScript existe também o *Arrow Function* que apesar de muito semelhante as "funções anonimas" ainda sim tem um ou outro comportamento diferente, como o exemplo aonde respondi: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/206881/3635, ainda não detalhei bem a resposta, porque não encontrei um fonte legal para usar de referencia, mas pretendo edita-la.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No conceito geral são sim, mas há detalhes diferentes.

Veja: [Qual a diferença entre uma expressão lambda, um closure e um delegate?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101).

Com isso entenda que há vários nomes para a mesma ou quase a mesma coisa.

Detalhes:

- [Como funcionam Closures em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1859/101)
- [Como funcionam funções anônimas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9936/101)
- [Criar classes tirando vantagem do lambda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/112597/101)
- [Quais as vantagens das Expressões Lambda presentes no Java 8?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269/101)
- [Variável não definida, mesmo estando definida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/206872/101)
- [O que são lambda expressions? E qual a sacada em usá-las?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2822/101) (é C#, mas ajuda entender).

Em ambas linguagens elas enclausuram variáveis, portanto são *closures*, e ambas usam a sintaxe simplificada de *lambda*, especialmente as versões mais novas do EcmaScript. A sintaxe antiga estava mais para função anônima. Antes de Java 8 não existia este recurso, nem nada parecido, apenas dava para conseguir o mesmo resultado com um bom trabalho extra, tudo manual, a linguagem não ajudava.

Ambas são funções que são atreladas à variáveis em qualquer lugar, incluindo parâmetros e retorno de funções. Elas podem ser chamadas através dessas variáveis.

Há um mito de que elas precisam estar dentro de outras funções. Elas só precisam ser atribuídas à uma variável, mesmo que indiretamente. Não precisam ser variáveis locais.

A maneira como a captura das variáveis e em que situações isso é possível muda. Especialmente me variáveis que não são locais.

Se quer saber se fazem tudo igual, se produzem exatamente o mesmo resultado usando igual, aí não há garantias e em alguns casos certamente é diferente.

Comment: _"Ambas usam a sintaxe simplificada de lambda, especialmente as versões mais novas do EcmaScript. A sintaxe antiga estava mais para função anônima"_. Lambdas e funções anônimas não são (exatamente ou mais ou menos) a mesma coisa? (no JavaScript, pelo menos, já que no Java lambdas seriam classes anônimas disfarçadas)

Comment: mais ou menos sim, exatamente não.

Answer (score 1):

Um lambda é apenas uma função anônima. Uma função que é definida sem nome. E o closures é, segundo o [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausura_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)):

> Uma closure ocorre normalmente quando uma função é declarada dentro do
>   corpo de outra, e a função interior referencia variáveis locais da
>   função exterior.

Ou seja, você têm uma função definida dentro de outra função a função interna utiliza de parâmetros e variáveis da função externa.

Comment: Coloca o link direto para a Wikipedia

Comment: Valeu! Achei muito interessante navegar para o Wikipedia em inglês e ver a etimologia da palavra  `closure`