# Dúvida com JavaScript arrow function

Tags: javascript, funções, ecmascript-5

No código abaixo, o método `showName()` naturalmente retornará `undefined`, pois irá buscar uma propriedade nome no escopo onde está inserido o obj.

A minha pergunta é, nesse caso eu obrigatoriamente teria que usar uma function convencional, a *arrow function* não serviria nesse caso?

```js
var obj = {
  nome: 'object',
  showName: () => {
    return this.nome
  }
}

console.log(obj.showName());
```

Comment: Dentro do `console.log` não deveria ser `showName()`?

Comment: Sim, já alterei, obrigado

Comment: quando se usa *arrow function*, dispensa o `return`.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Variável não definida, mesmo estando definida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206872/vari%c3%a1vel-n%c3%a3o-definida-mesmo-estando-definida). PS: o this não vai funcionar neste caso, estou analisando o ecma para ver detalhamentos e atualizar a resposta, lhe notificarei.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento minha dúvida é qual a melhor forma de escrever isso e não a questão do escopo.

Comment: @FelipeCoelho por isso estou lendo na ecma pra ver se tem outra maneira, não to falando de escopo, estou falando do que é possivel até o momento conforme o ecmascript ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento ok, obrigado

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O melhor nesse caso é usar uma `function` "normal". Esse é um caso de beco sem saída. O objeto é criado num dado contexto, a *arrow function* vai usar o contexto no momento da criação e não pode por isso apontar para si próprio.

Dá para criar um cenário parecido, em que isso ia funcionar, mas é pleno exercício, não estou a ver um caso de uso que não dê para fazer de outra maneira:

```js
var obj = (function() {
    this.nome = 'object';
    this.showName = () => {
        return this.nome;
    }
    return this;
}).call({});

console.log(obj.showName()); // object
```

O mesmo já não se aplica a classes, que seria mais interessante que um objeto simples (pois se tens arrow functions podes benefeciar de classes ES6). Nesse caso a classe cria um contexto próprio e a *arrow function* seria muito útil:

```js
class Obj {
  constructor() {
    this.nome = 'object',
      this.showName = () => {
        return this.nome;
      }
  }
}
var obj = new Obj();
console.log(obj.showName()); // object
```

Ou usando notação com [class properties](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields) (em fase de proposta/estudo para implementar na linguagem).

```js
class Obj {
  nome = 'object';
  showName = () => {
    return this.nome;
  }

}
var obj = new Obj();
console.log(obj.showName()); // object
```