# This e arrow function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Porque que quando uso arrow function ele retorna undefined. Porém quando uso uma função normal ele funciona corretamente. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Fala aí, Diego! Poste seus códigos em forma de texto, ao invés de prints! [Edite sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/354566/edit) e clique no botão `{}` para formatar o código!

Comment: Essa maneira que está tentando é erronea. É uma dúvida duplicada:  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/209506/d%C3%BAvida-com-javascript-arrow-function

Comment: Pow vlw borther,é pq é minha primeira pergunta aqui kk