# Solução de problema em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

Sou novo no javascript, estou fazendo uns exercícios de fixação, mas estou tendo problema no caso abaixo.

Criar uma função chamada maiorAlto que retorne verdadeiro (true) caso ele atenda os requisitos(Ter 18 anos ou mais e ter uma altura igual ou maior a 1,70), e falso (false) para o contrário. Nessa função os parâmetro que será um array, contendo na primeira posição a idade do aluno e na segunda contendo a altura em Centímetros.

```
function maiorAlto(usuario){
   if (maiorAlto.length){
      if (maiorAlto.length){
         return usuario5[1] <= 18 || usuario5[2] <=170
      }
      else{
        return usuario5[1] >= 18 || usuario5[2] >=170
      }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o @Leo-Letto e o @hkotsubojá falaram tudo, só vim aqui para colocar outra opção de código ...

```
<script>
function maiorAlto(usuario){
  
   if (usuario[1] >= 18 && usuario[2] >=170){
        alert("True");
        return true;
    
   }
   else{
        alert("False");
        return false;
  }

}


var usuario1 = ['Et da Estônia', 17, 170]
var usuario2 = ['Pessoa do Pântano', 39, 198]
var usuario3 = ['Homem da Lua Virada', 21, 149]
var usuario4 = ['Pequena Paulistana', 18, 171]
var usuario5 = ['Menino da Porteira', 13, 142]

var resultado=maiorAlto(usuario4)
</script>
```

Uma maneira beeemmm mais tradicional de fazer (como vc disse que é novo em js), dá para rodar o código acima [aqui](https://js.do/code/465020), todos que responderam a essa pergunta solucionaram o problema, tudo depende qual nível léxico você prefere trabalhar, não sei se tem diferença de performance(execução) entre as três opções dadas, mas você pode perceber como tem uma sintaxe mais limpa as outras opções dadas  ...

Comment: Neste caso em especifico não tem praticamente nenhuma diferença de performance, mas para o caso dele não é necessário tratar nenhum dado ao interno da função, simplesmente controlar os parâmetros passados, então uma vez feito o `AND` com os dois valores, não é necessário fazer mais um check com um `if` visto que o valor controlado antes é já o resultado final a ser retornado, você está fazendo um outro controle em cima de um valor que já foi controlado basicamente.

Comment: No caso o resultado do emulador que estou usando esta dando a seguinte resposta -> Erros:
A função maiorAlto deve retornar true quando executada com as informações: maiorAlto(["Et da Estônia", 18, 170])
A função maiorAlto deve retornar false quando executada com as informações: maiorAlto(['Homem da Lua Virada', 21, 149]), ate a ultima que é do usuario5, sendo que a parte da function para baixo foi eu que criei eles so me passaram os parâmetros dos usuários.

Comment: Respondendo ao Leo, na solução deste problema em especifico eles pedem para usar o IF.

Comment: Na teoria é isso que eu também imagino, mas o processador vai ter que fazer uma operação lógica de qualquer maneira, um dia poderíamos testar se tem algum ganho de performance, seria legal, eu tenho bastante interesse de saber se no fim das contas faz diferença em execução, na faculdade eu lembro que os meus professores me obrigavam a fazer esses testes de performance, mas nunca fiz nada assim com JS rsrs ....

Comment: @BRUNOMARTINSFERNANDES rapaz foi o que eu imaginei hahaha é algo para quem tá começando, então eles vão querer um exercício com IF rsrs, aparentemente meu código deve atender o que vc precisa ...

Answer (score 2):

Você recebe come input nesta função um array que é feito neste modo:

`[idade, altura]`

Você pode fazer algo simples como:

```
function maiorAlto(usuario){
   return (usuario[0] >= 18 && usuario[1] >= 170);
}
```

Você deixar ainda mais simples aplicando uma Arrow Function:

```
const maiorAlto = (usuario) => (usuario[0] >= 18 && usuario[1] >= 170);
```

Explicação do retorno:

`usuario[0]` contém a idade do usuário passado como parametro, ao confrontar a mesma com `>= 18` isto irá retornar `true` se o usuário tem mais de 18 anos, caso contrário `false`, em seguida adicionamos um `&& (AND)` para verificar também a altura com `usuario[1] >= 170`, em palavras isso seria algo como:

True: SE idade maior que ou igual a 18 E altura maior que ou igual a 170.

Se uma das afirmações não forem ou ambas true/verdade, a função irá retornar `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays [começam do índice zero](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements) (o primeiro índice é o zero, o segundo é 1, etc).

Além disso, para verificar se duas condições são verdadeiras usa-se o [operador `&&` (and)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) e não o [`||` (or)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR).

Dito isso, sua função seria apenas isso:

```js
function maiorAlto(usuario) {
    return usuario[0] >= 18 && usuario[1] >= 170;
}

console.log(maiorAlto([18, 170])); // true
console.log(maiorAlto([25, 210])); // true
console.log(maiorAlto([17, 180])); // false
console.log(maiorAlto([19, 150])); // false
```

Ou seja, se a idade for maior ou igual a 18 **e** a altura for maior ou igual a 170, a expressão toda resulta em `true`. Se qualquer uma das condições não for verdade (ou a idade é menor que 18, ou a altura for menor que 170, ou ambos), o retorno é `false`.

Não faz sentido ter o `if (maiorAlto.length)` (e tê-lo duas vezes seguidas faz menos sentido ainda). O atributo `length` de uma função indica a [quantidade de parâmetros que ela espera receber](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Length), não há motivo para usá-lo aqui.

E dentro da função você usa `usuario5`, sendo que o parâmetro se chama `usuario`, então nunca funcionaria corretamente.

O que talvez devesse ser feito é verificar se o array `usuario` tem mesmo 2 elementos e eles são números, mas não parece ser requisito do exercício.

---

> Eu só discordo da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/461105/112052) quanto ao fato da *arrow function* ser "mais simples". Isso é relativo: para mim, dependendo do caso, fica até mais confuso (e em caso de uma função simples como essa, eu acho até uma complicação desnecessária, sem nenhum ganho de fato). Vale lembrar também que uma *arrow function* nem sempre será 100% equivalente a uma função declarada com `function`, veja mais sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143399/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/209506/112052) e [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (não é o caso da função acima, mas é importante saber as diferenças, em vez de usar só porque parece "mais simples" ou "mais legal").