# JavaScript - Dados do Usuário

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde! estou tendando resolver o exercicio abaixo porém não estou conseguindo, montei o código porém não deu certo, poderiam me ajudar?

Em uma  academia está acontecendo um cadastro de vários usuários contendo as seguintes informações: nome, idade e altura. E para realizar um determinado treino, existe alguns requisitos: Ter 18 anos ou mais e ter uma altura igual ou maior a 1,70.

Crie uma função chamada maiorAlto que retorne verdadeiro (true) caso ele atenda os requisitos, e falso (false) para o contrário. Nessa função você irá receber um parâmetro que será um array, contendo na primeira posição o nome, segunda posição a idade do aluno e na terceira contendo a altura em Centímetros.

Exemplo

```
maiorAlto(["Aluno incrível", 18, 170]) // retorna true
maiortAlto(["Aluno baixo", 17, 150]) // retorna false
```

Dicas:Lembre-se que para criar uma função usamos a palavra function
No array de informações, a idade do usuário vem primeiro, segundo a altura (que está em centímetros)
Para acessar a posição de um array bata colocar o nome seguido de colchetes: array[1]

Abaixo o código que fiz:

```
var usuario2 = ['Pessoa do Pântano', 39, 198]
var usuario3 = ['Homem da Lua Virada', 21, 149]
var usuario4 = ['Pequena Paulistana', 18, 171]
var usuario5 = ['Menino da Porteira', 13, 142]

function maiorAlto(["nome", 18, 170]) {

    for (var i = 0; i < maiorAlto.length; i++) {

        if (usuario1[2] == 18 && usuario1[3] == 170)

            return true; false

        if (usuario2[2] == 18 && usuario2[3] == 170)

            return true; false
        if (usuario3[2] == 18 && usuario3[3] == 170)

            return true; false
        if (usuario4[2] == 18 && usuario4[3] == 170)

            return true; false
        if (usuario5[2] == 18 && usuario5[3] == 170)

            return true; false
    }
}
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Solução de problema em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/461100/solu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-problema-em-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

No enunciado informa que a função recebe array:

**Nessa função você irá receber um parâmetro que será um array**

*function maiorAlto(array){ }*

(o parâmetro pode ser qualquer nome e não necessariamente o nome array, tá?)

É preciso >= 18 anos e >= 170, sabemos que a posição da idade é [1] e da altura é [2], então a função ficará assim:

```
function maiorAlto(array){
    if(array[1] >=18 && array[2] >=170){
        return true
    }else{
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var usuario1 = ['Et da Estônia', 17, 170]
var usuario2 = ['Pessoa do Pântano', 39, 198]
var usuario3 = ['Homem da Lua Virada', 21, 149]
var usuario4 = ['Pequena Paulistana', 18, 171]
var usuario5 = ['Menino da Porteira', 13, 142]


var usuario1 = ['Et da Estônia', 17, 170]
var usuario2 = ['Pessoa do Pântano', 39, 198]
var usuario3 = ['Homem da Lua Virada', 21, 149]
var usuario4 = ['Pequena Paulistana', 18, 171]
var usuario5 = ['Menino da Porteira', 13, 142]

function maiorAlto(usuario) {

    if (usuario[1] >= 18 && usuario[2] >= 170) {
        return true;

    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

}

var usuario1 = ['Et da Estônia', 17, 170]
var usuario2 = ['Pessoa do Pântano', 39, 198]
var usuario3 = ['Homem da Lua Virada', 21, 149]
var usuario4 = ['Pequena Paulistana', 18, 171]
var usuario5 = ['Menino da Porteira', 13, 142]

var resultado = maiorAlto(usuario4)
```

```js
function maiorAlto(usuario) {

    if (usuario[1] >= 18 && usuario[2] >= 170) {
        return true;

    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

}

var usuario1 = ['Et da Estônia', 17, 170];
var usuario2 = ['Pessoa do Pântano', 39, 198];
var usuario3 = ['Homem da Lua Virada', 21, 149];
var usuario4 = ['Pequena Paulistana', 18, 171];
var usuario5 = ['Menino da Porteira', 13, 142];

//var resultado = maiorAlto(usuario1);

console.log("usuario1 = " +maiorAlto(usuario1));
console.log("usuario2 = " +maiorAlto(usuario2));
console.log("usuario3 = " +maiorAlto(usuario3));
console.log("usuario4 = " +maiorAlto(usuario4));
console.log("usuario5 = " +maiorAlto(usuario5));
```

Comment: acho que minha edição ajudou um pouco!! A sua resposta é ótima mas tem  trechos de código repetidos

Comment: Sim! foi fundamental. Obrigado!!

Answer (score 0):

Para facilitar, você pode criar um array de objetos passando os dados dos alunos em uma única varíavel, para mais tarde percorre-la em sua função. Para declarar vários usuários em uma única varíavel de objetos, podemos fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
let usuarios = [
    { nome: 'Pessoa do Pântano', idade: 39, altura: 198 },
    { nome: 'Homem da Lua Virada', idade: 21, altura: 149 },
    { nome: 'Pequena Paulistana', idade: 18, altura: 171 },
    { nome: 'Menino da Porteira', idade: 13, altura: 142 }
];
```

Em específico a sua função, você pode adicionar duas condições, verificando se a idade é maior ou igual a 18 e a altura maior que 170, conforme pede no enunciado:

> Ter 18 anos ou mais e ter uma altura igual ou maior a 1,70.

```
function maiorAlto(usuario) {
    return usuario.idade >= 18 && usuario.altura >= 170;
}
```

Com isso já resolveria o problema, contudo, para podermos testar, podemos percorrer o nosso vetor chamando a nossa função (que retorna true ou false), permitindo assim sabermos se determinado aluno se enquadra no treino ou não.

O código final da solução ficará da seguinte maneira:

```js
let usuarios = [
    { nome: 'Pessoa do Pântano', idade: 39, altura: 198 },
    { nome: 'Homem da Lua Virada', idade: 21, altura: 149 },
    { nome: 'Pequena Paulistana', idade: 18, altura: 171 },
    { nome: 'Menino da Porteira', idade: 13, altura: 142 }
];

function maiorAlto(usuario) {
    return usuario.idade >= 18 && usuario.altura >= 170;
}

for (let count = 0; count < usuarios.length; count++) {
    if (maiorAlto(usuarios[count])) {
        console.log(`Aluno "${usuarios[count].nome}" atende aos requisitos do treino.`)
    } else {
        console.log(`Aluno "${usuarios[count].nome}" não atende aos requisitos do treino.`)
    }
}
```