# JavaScript - Dados do Usuário duvida

Tags: javascript

*if (usuario[1] >= 18 && usuario[2] >= 170) {*

**Essa linha de codigo abaixo fiquei com duvida alguem me explica por favor, pra mim nao faz muito sentido pegar o usuario 1 e o usuario 2 para verificar se e true ou false, posso estar enganado mas nao teria que ser usado um usuario para todos ?**

Em uma academia está acontecendo um cadastro de vários usuários contendo as seguintes informações: nome, idade e altura. E para realizar um determinado treino, existe alguns requisitos: Ter 18 anos ou mais e ter uma altura igual ou maior a 1,70.

Crie uma função chamada maiorAlto que retorne verdadeiro (true) caso ele atenda os requisitos, e falso (false) para o contrário. Nessa função você irá receber um parâmetro que será um array, contendo na primeira posição o nome, segunda posição a idade do aluno e na terceira contendo a altura em Centímetros.

Exemplo

maiorAlto(["Aluno incrível", 18, 170]) // retorna true
maiortAlto(["Aluno baixo", 17, 150]) // retorna false
Dicas:Lembre-se que para criar uma função usamos a palavra function No array de informações, a idade do usuário vem primeiro, segundo a altura (que está em centímetros) Para acessar a posição de um array bata colocar o nome seguido de colchetes: array[1]

function maiorAlto(usuario) {

```
*if (usuario[1] >= 18 && usuario[2] >= 170)* {
    return true;

}
else {
    return false;
}
```

}

var usuario1 = ['Et da Estônia', 17, 170];
var usuario2 = ['Pessoa do Pântano', 39, 198];
var usuario3 = ['Homem da Lua Virada', 21, 149];
var usuario4 = ['Pequena Paulistana', 18, 171];
var usuario5 = ['Menino da Porteira', 13, 142];

//var resultado = maiorAlto(usuario1);

console.log("usuario1 = " +maiorAlto(usuario1));
console.log("usuario2 = " +maiorAlto(usuario2));
console.log("usuario3 = " +maiorAlto(usuario3));
console.log("usuario4 = " +maiorAlto(usuario4));
console.log("usuario5 = " +maiorAlto(usuario5));

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Solução de problema em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/461100/solu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-problema-em-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está correto.

Isso é a utilização de array (vetor ou matriz) de variáveis.

Observe que:
`var usuario1 = ['Et da Estônia', 17, 170];`

É o mesmo que:

`usuario1[0]  = 'Et da Estônia'; usuario1[1] = 17; usuario1[2] = 170;`

São dados do mesmo usuário. Respectivamente nome, idade e altura.

Então a sua função ficaria assim:

```
function maiorAlto(usuario){
return (usuario[1] >= 18 && usuario[2] >= 170);
```

}

Note que o retorno da função já é booleano, então você pode escrever a expressão condicional já no return, não sendo necessário verificar com if() para utilizar return true.

Exemplo de chamada para essa função:

```
var usuario1 = ['Eduardo', 17, 175];
console.log(maiorAlto(usuario1));
```

---

No caso de trabalhar com Array Multidimensional como:

```
var usuarios = [ { nome: 'Pessoa do Pântano', idade: 39, altura: 198 }, { nome: 'Homem da Lua Virada', idade: 21, altura: 149 }, { nome: 'Pequena Paulistana', idade: 18, altura: 171 }, { nome: 'Menino da Porteira', idade: 13, altura: 142 } ];
```

Você terá que fazer um loop para acessar cada objeto dentro do array. Há duas formas de fazer, loop for com um contador ou loop foreach.

Loop for:

```
    function maiorAlto(usuario){
for(i = 0; i < usuario.length; i ++)
    console.log(usuario[i].idade >= 18 && usuario[i].altura >= 170);
```

}

`maiorAlto(usuarios);`

Ou,utilizando forEach:

```
function maiorAlto(usuario){
console.log(usuario.idade >= 18 && usuario.altura >= 170);
```

}

Utilizando a chamada para a função dessa forma:

```
usuarios.forEach(maiorAlto);
```

Recomendo leitura desses artigos para maior esclarecimento:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multidimensional-array-in-javascript/
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Olha to com duvida de como fazer meu IF se fizesse uma unica variavel para os usuarios assim :                    
 var usuarios = [
    { nome: 'Pessoa do Pântano', idade: 39, altura: 198 },
    { nome: 'Homem da Lua Virada', idade: 21, altura: 149 },
    { nome: 'Pequena Paulistana', idade: 18, altura: 171 },
    { nome: 'Menino da Porteira', idade: 13, altura: 142 }
];  E nao uma variavel para cada usuario

Answer (score -2):

O If já retorna true ou false, não precisa especificar isso no corpo dele. basta dar um return usuario;

Comment: Entendi, so que o if nao ficaria aplicado somente na variavel 1 e 2 ? Devido eu ter escolhido somente essas duas variaveis dentro do if. Nao teria que ser um if que conte-se todos os usuarios ?

Comment: Aí no caso você tem que fazer um for, pra poder comparar todos os usuários. O ideal é você criar uma variável usuários do tipo array, pra armazenar todos os usuários e fazer um for percorrendo todas as posições do array. Dentro do for for você cria uma variável pra guardar o maior e aí você usaria um if pra verificar se o novo usuário é maior que o último. Aí no final você retorna o maior.