# Função com três parâmetros em Javascript. Erro ao retornar "true" ou "false". O que fazer?

Tags: javascript, array, funções

Preciso de um código que sinalize TRUE quando a idade for >= 21 anos e a altura >= 180 cm. O código que fiz não está funcionando e não sei qual erro apresenta. =/

```
function maiorAlto(nome , idade , altura) {
    if (idade >=21 && altura >= 181) {
        return true 
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
 
 maiorAlto(['Laura', 21, 187])
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Solução de problema em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/461100/solu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-problema-em-javascript)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você está passando os parâmetros de forma incorreta na chamada da função.

O correto seria:

```
maiorAlto('Laura', 21, 187);
```

Nesse código também está faltando ponto-e-vírgula para indicar o final das instruções.

Agora, caso você queira passar um array como parâmetro, então a função é que está escrita de forma errada. Deveria ser:

```
function maiorAlto(pessoa) {
    if (pessoa[1] >=21 && pessoa[2] >= 181) {
        return true; 
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Observe que como o retorno esperado é booleano (true ou false) você não precisa utilizar if. Poderia fazer dessa forma:

```
function maiorAlto(pessoa) {
        return (pessoa[1] >=21 && pessoa[2] >= 181);
}
```